# is $1/x$ a measurable function on $(0,1)$?

Tags: measure-theory

I know that

Def. Let $f$ be an extended real valued function defined on a measurable set E. Then  $f$  is a Lebesgue-measurable function or, more briefly, a measurable function if, for each $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ the set  $[x:f(x)>\alpha]$ is measurable.

Clearly in this case $$[x:f(x)>\alpha]$$ is $[x:\frac{1}{x}> \alpha] = [x:x<\frac{1}{\alpha}]$

is that set measurable, if so, why?

Comment: Yes, all continuous functions are Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Since the Lebesgue measure is complete, $f$ need only be defined ae., and the function $g(x) = {1 \over x}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $g(0) = 0$ is measurable. It is not clear how you define ${1 \over x}$ for $x=0$, so it is hard to say if the above sets are equivalent.

Comment: if $\alpha > 0 $ then $[x:x < \frac{1}{\alpha}] = (0,\frac{1}{\alpha}) $ and that has measure $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ right? and in the other hand if $\alpha <0$ so we have the empty set and has measure 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f(x)=1/x$ and $x\in (0,1).$

Now let $a \in \mathbb R.$

Case 1: $a \le 0.$ Then $\{x \in (0,1): f(x)>a\}=(0,1)$.

Case 2: $a>0.$ $\{x \in (0,1): f(x)>a\}=\{x \in(0,1): x < \frac{1}{a}\}=(0,1) \cap ( - \infty, \frac{1}{a}).$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: I think so, but in the case 2, is $(-\infty,\frac{1}{\alpha})$ measurable?

Comment: Each intervall in $ \mathbb R$ is measurable !